# Add prefix to default auth routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I have added a prefix user to the default auth routes so that i can achieve example.com/user/login routes. Everything works well except the password reset email sent to the user's email address. When clicked on the link in the email it goes to the default reset route. How to add prefix user to this link in the email.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code if it helps

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function () {
      Auth::routes();
      Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    });
```

Comment: are you using any email template for sending reset password email ? Or the default one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your notification class for password reset

```
php artisan make:notification MailResetPasswordToken
```

after that edit this file which you find in a new folder `App\Notifications` and change `url('password/reset', $this->token)` to `url('user/password/reset', $this->token)`

```
namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class MailResetPasswordToken extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $token;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject("Reset your password")
                    ->line("Hey, did you forget your password? Click the button to reset it.")
                    ->action('Reset Password', url('user/password/reset', $this->token))
                    ->line('Thankyou for being a friend');
    }

}
```

Override the send password reset trait with your local implementation in your `User.php`  user model. be sure your `User` model should have used `Notifiable` trait

```
/**
 * Send a password reset email to the user
 */
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
    $this->notify(new MailResetPasswordToken($token));
}
```

Import these class to `User` model

```
use App\Notifications\MailResetPasswordToken;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
```

Comment: Wonderful. I also learnt how to add more lines to the email message from your code. Thank you so much.